# Output from curl is null

Tags: php, json, curl

Hello i have never worked with curls in php before, i am trying to get the curl output that i also get when using it in the command line.

Here is what i have tried

```
$url = 'curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: MY KEY HERE"';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));

$result = file_get_contents($url);

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

Those two `var_dumps` both get me the output `NULL`.

I am aware that my url is not correct, but i am not sure waht to change.

Comment: You should put only url into `$url`. Other configurations should be set `$ch` like Method GET headers

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

Comment: I get that, but where to i put my autho-key since im not just curling like in all examples that i found https://google.com

Comment: If you're not familiar with using curl in PHP, you should make sure that the requested curl command fetches what you're looking for. Run it directly in the command line, or use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to easily and powerfully test API inputs.